# How to enable logging of com.sibvisions.util.Mail

Tags: jvx

I have a simple application and on some value changes a workflow is triggered. The workflow sends emails with `com.sibvisions.util.Mail` class.

My code looks like:

```
Mail m = new Mail("server", "587", "user", "password");
m.setTLSEnabled(true);
m.setContentType(Mail.CONTENT_HTML);
m.send("from@domain.com", "to@domain.com", "Subject", "Message");
```

Some users told me that they didn't receive an email. I want to find out if the problem is in my application. So, how is it possible to log mail transport?

I know that it's possible to add my own log output before `m.send(...)` but this doesn't log the mail transport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mail transport logging is not related to JVx because it just uses [Java Mail API](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/). To enable logging, just configure the log level of:

`com.sun.mail.level = ALL`

This log level logs all mail transports. The API documentation contains logger information at the end of package summaries, e.g.

https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html

Just put your log definition in your `logging.properties` and JVx will read this automatically. It's also possible to set the log level programmatically:

`LoggerFactory.getInstance("com.sun.mail").setLevel(LogLevel.ALL);`

But I recommend using `logging.properties` file.